# Сложность функций из cmath

Tags: c++

Как можно узнать сложность функций из `<cmath>`? Например, какая асимптотика у `std::exp()` или `std::pow()`? На `cppreference` не нашёл.

Comment: Не уверен, что для математических функций вообще имеет смысл говорить о сложности. Всё-таки они запускаются для конкретного набора аргумента, а не для последовательностей произвольной длинны.

Comment: @Александр ну так сложность от величины параметров функций

Comment: Вы хотите узнать что-то из разряда насколько `std::exp(10000)` будет отличаться по быстродействию от `std::exp(1)`?

Comment: @älёxölüt да___

Answer (score 1):

Понятие сложности алгоритма определяет временн*у*ю длительность и объём занимаемой памяти при его выполнении в зависимости от изменения количества элементов входной последовательности. Например, всевозможные методы сортировок могут иметь сложность `n^2`, `n*log(n)` и т.п.

Применительно к математическим функциям, типа упомянутых `std::pow` или `std::exp` нельзя говорить о такой сложности. А учитывая, что в реализациях функций (спасибо @Komdosh за смежный ответ) нет циклов, зависимых от входных значений, то и про зависимость длительности вычислений от значения аргумента говорить не приходится. Более того, реализациям не накладываются какие-то ни было ограничения, поэтому совершенно спокойно на одной машине `std::exp` может работать быстрее, чем `std::pow`, а на другой совсем наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от функций и реализаций. Для `std::pow(a, b)` это обычно `O(log b)`. Стандарт это не оговаривает

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что это все же считается как `exp(b*log(a))` за O(1) :)